# Can I use spread syntax(...) in vue.js 2.x template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can I use something like this in vue.js template?

```html
<template>
  <vxe-table>
    <vxe-column
      v-for="options in someConsts"
      ...options
      width="160">
    </vxe-column>
  </vxe-table>
</template>
```

like in React.js, where `options` may be something like `{title: 'ColName', width: 160, formatter: ...}`.

I did this, but got

```
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '...options' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Comment: no - what do you imagine the result could be

Comment: You can use any valid JS code in Vue (the syntax may be different from React tho). So, depending on exactly what you want to do here (more context is welcome), you could totally spread some state or `...rest` the remaining to the `el-xxx` child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `15. Stealing Prop Types` [from here](https://dev.to/michaelthiessen/25-vue-tips-you-need-to-know-2h70).

One thing to keep in mind is that you're not in a JSX realm anymore here.
As for your edit, `...options` by itself doesn't make sense.
Meanwhile, `:options="options"` is a valid yet simple approach (the right part of `options` can totally contain a `...rest` of course).

Be careful of not drilling the state too hard tho.
[provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) is also a viable solution overall.
As for the exact syntax, I recommend reading the official doc to get it right.

The main difference here, is that `xve-column` is not an object as in React, more of a web component syntax. Expecting a key/pair value like `width` in your case.

Also, give a try to `v-bind="$props"` as [explained here](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind).